# Serve HTTPS response from Squid cache even if upstream server is unreachable

Tags: squid

I have configured Squid with `ssl_bump` so that it can man-in-the-middle HTTPS connections and cache the replies, like so:

```
http_port 3128 ssl-bump \
  cert=/etc/squid/certs/squid-ca-cert-and-key.pem \
  generate-host-certificates=on dynamic_cert_mem_cache_size=16MB

acl step1 at_step SslBump1
ssl_bump peek step1
ssl_bump bump all
```

I would like Squid to accept the client's connection and try to serve the response from its cache *before* trying to connect to the upstream server.

However, it tries to connect to the server first, returning a 503 error if the server isn't reachable (because the network is offline, say):

```
1635102093.658     13 172.17.0.1 NONE/200 0 CONNECT deb.nodesource.com:443 - HIER_NONE/- -
1635102093.673      0 172.17.0.1 NONE/503 4110 GET https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x - HIER_NONE/- text/html
```

When the network is available and the upstream host is reachable, then Squid will happily serve from its in-memory cache:

```
1635102172.772    101 172.17.0.1 NONE/200 0 CONNECT deb.nodesource.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/18.2.197.72 -
1635102172.792      1 172.17.0.1 TCP_MEM_HIT/200 14319 GET https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x - HIER_NONE/- text/plain
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `client-first` seems to work:

```
acl step1 at_step SslBump1
ssl_bump client-first step1
ssl_bump bump all
```

However this is a long-deprecated option and it will not work to interpose every kind of TLS connection.